# How to make this query better in SQL for this repeated query in 'from clause'

Tags: sql

Is there any way to make this query better by removing repeated pattern of select in from clause?  What is the best efficient way to write this query?  I am using SQLite.

```
select abs(avg(ravg1) - avg(ravg2))
from (select avg(stars) as ravg1 
      from Movie M join
           Rating R
           on M.mID = R.mID 
      group by R.mID
      having year < 1980
     ), 
     (select avg(stars) as ravg2 
      from Movie M join
      Rating R on M.mID = R.mID 
      group by R.mID
      having year > 1980
     )
```

Comment: What database are you using?  And what do you think this query is doing?  I doubt it is doing what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the difference in ratings for years before and after 1980, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
  select abs(avg(case when year < 1980 then stars end) -
             avg(case when year > 1980 then stars end)
            )
  from Movie M join
       Rating R
       on M.mID = R.mID;
```

Comment: @Twelfth . . . I went back and forth on that issue.  The final query returns only one row, so in the end, I went without the `group by`.